# RelativeLayout in CoordinatorLayout doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` within my `CoordinatorLayout` (as shown below). Also notice that within the `RelativeLayout` I have a `RecyclerView`.

However, when I scroll, I can only scroll on the `RecyclerView` and *only* the `RecyclerView` portion of the screen will actually scroll. If I try scrolling on the layout above the `RecyclerView`, it won't scroll the screen at all. Here's an illustration I made of what's going on:

[image: Demo]

So my question is, why can't I scroll on the inner `RelativeLayout`? Should I be organizing my layouts in a different way?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp">

                // some imageviews and textviews

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` is not scrollable if it's not within any Scrollable View. 
Try putting your `RelativeLayout` as a Header of your `RecyclerView`.

In this example you will be able to scroll its content

```
<ScrollView 
     ...
     ...>
         <!-- Scrollable Contents -->
</ScrollView>
```

In your case I think the best way is to let your `RecyclerView` take up the whole screen and then assign its header. Follow this [link](https://inducesmile.com/android/add-header-to-android-recyclerview/) or [this](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/10/adding-header-and-footer-layouts-for.html). There's many out there so just google it up

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this can be done using single `recyclerview` and putting your header `relativelayout` as an item of `recyclerview`.

May you are familiar with `getItemViewType` method, that is used to decide item type of recyclerview item.

Add data to your `dataset` using which you'll be going to decide type of an item. Consider below example...

```
    public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final int ITEM_ROW = 1;
    private final int ITEM_HEADER = 2;

    // Will be your dataset which will be containing first item as relativeLayout payload.
    private ArrayList<Object> mData;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Object> mData) {
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (viewType == ITEM_ROW) {
            // Inflate your row item of recyclerview here...

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_checkout_review_cart_item, parent, false);
            vh = new ItemHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_HEADER) {

            // Inflate your relativeLayout here...

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_order_detail_grand_total_item, parent, false);
            vh = new RelativeLayoutHolder(view);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof ItemHolder) {

            // Bind item of recyclerview here...

        } else if (holder instanceof RelativeLayoutHolder) {

            // Bind data of your relativeLayout

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Decide type of an item using payload instances..
        Object obj = mData.get(position);
        if (obj instanceof ItemInfo) {
            return ITEM_ROW;
        } else if (obj instanceof RelativeLayoutInfo) {
            return ITEM_HEADER;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class RelativeLayoutHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RelativeLayoutHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Your `Payload of dataset` will decide itemType. Two type of `Pojo` will going to be inserted into your `dataset` -  `RelativeLayoutInfo` and `ItemInfo`. For an example

```
public class ItemInfo implements Serializable {

     // Consider adding object and getter setter here
}
```

and

```
public class RelativeLayoutInfo implements Serializable {

   // Consider adding object and getter setter here
}
```

There you go. your `relativeLayout` is added as an item of `recyclerview`.
Happy coding!!